# Inkscape: Draw a man and a boy

Tags: inkscape, logo

I am new to Inkscape and tasked to develop a logo of a man rubbing/touching the head of a boy, for an orphan foundation we are establishing.

I would appreciate if someone could help with a brief description on how to draw something like the following picture in Inkscape(not necessarily exact picture, just a man touching head of an orphan to show concern), to help me quickly develop the logo and meet the deadline.

[image]

Comment: You want a "brief description on how to draw"??? In words and sentences? Please give us an example of what you want to read; use a simple example where you describe how to draw anything very simple (cup, hat, hammer). That way we can better understand what you want.

Comment: Have you tried to follow a character design tutorial? The net is plenty of these (e.g. [this](https://2dgameartguru.com/creating-a-game-character/), , [this](https://youtu.be/Dk7oltlih7k), [this](https://youtu.be/myWth-f5q9Y) or [this](https://youtu.be/uOV0NRsuo80)). Else, have you searched for already made characters? Can you tell us something about your efforts?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to learn about our community. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see *what* makes a good query here *and* how to ask it. We ***do*** ask that questions show *some effort*: *show us what you tried and where/how that effort failed*; illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples. I'm afraid that as currently written, your question is super-broad and likely to get closed: read [ask] and [edit] your question to better fit our guidelines; you'll get better answers too! Thanks & again, welcome!

Comment: Why do you accept a work without knowing how to draw, or use an application?

Answer (score 0):

it's useful if you have a sketch which resembles as accurately as possible the objective you seek. "Just like the following picture" is merely a reference and not particularly useful to reach your goal.

Can you sketch out with paper and pencil the design you require? If you cannot start with a hand-made work of art, it's going to be nearly impossible to create something using a computer program. If you can create a hand-drawn image, you're more than halfway to your finished design.

Consider that you can take a paper sketch and import the image into Inkscape. Use the trace bitmap feature which will give you a series of vectors that can be edited to clean up the picture.

It's common that a hand drawn sketch will have plenty of artifacts to be removed. Some lines will be too thin to appear, others may to thicker than you desire. If you can trace your sketch with ink or dark marker, your trace results will be better.